# Adding ' at the start of each row of a table through sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a column called "product-code". These are all populated. I am wanting to do a query that will insert a ' at the start of each field and then another query to add a ' at the end of the field.

So for example at the moment a product code might be fmx-2, after the query I would want it to look like 'fmx-22'

I am looking to do this for all the data sets within the table. I am using Microsoft Access

Thanks

Comment: wouldn't it be better to fix your issues in the code, rather than add useless data to your table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Microsoft Access you can use `&` char to concatenate string, and your query could be something similar:

```
update my_table set product_code = "'" & product_code & "'";
```